# Setting up py2app to run selenium

Tags: python, selenium, package, py2app

I am having problems getting py2app to work with my python webscraper program that uses Selenium.

I know that I have to include selenium in my packages, but nothing is working. I can't see an error message because the .app won't open.

The imports in my python fie look like this.

```
#! python3
import urllib
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import pdb
```

And my setup.py file looks like this

```
    """
This is a setup.py script generated by py2applet

Usage:
    python setup.py py2app
"""

from setuptools import setup

APP = ['highlights.py']
DATA_FILES = ['doi_list.txt']
OPTIONS = {'argv_emulation': True
           'packages': ['urllib', 'pdb', 'selenium'] 
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

I followed Marina Mele's [py2app tutorial](http://www.marinamele.com/from-a-python-script-to-a-portable-mac-application-with-py2app) but she just brushes over including packages, and I have no idea how to do this. I'm new to programming.

Do you know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try this:

```
driver_path = 'xxxx/chromedriver'  # path of your chromedriver
DATA_FILES = ['doi_list.txt', driver_path]
```

It works for me.

And make sure `app/Contents/Resources/chromedriver` has the permissions to execute.

Right click your app, select "show Package Contents".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'packages', try using 'includes'. (Works in py2app v0.13)

```
OPTIONS = {
        'argv_emulation': True,
        'includes': ['httplib2', 'requests', 'selenium']
        }
```

PS: make sure to include commas to separate list entries